# How to access reference source object in Spring Flux error handler?

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux

I have a list of blocking web requests as `List<Mono>` that I want to execute concurrently.

The following works in general, BUT: when an exception occurs, I want to collect all errors in a Map assigned to the request that caused the exception.

```
List<Request> bodies;
List<Mono<Response>> monos = requests.stream().map(bodies -> prepareMono(body)).collect(Collectors.toList());

Map<Request, Throwable> errors = new HashMap<>();

List<Response> results = Flux.merge(monos).collectList().onErrorContinue((ex, value) -> {
            //TODO how can I access the <Request> here who caused the exception
            errors.put(<request>, ex);
        }).block();

private Mono<Response> prepareMono(Object body) {
    return webClient.post().syncBody(body).retrieve().bodyToMono(Response.class);
}
```

Problem: how can I access the request body that I sent inside the error handler?

Comment: onErrorResume()

Comment: dont ever do `block()` in a reactive application. And if you really must you have to wrap each an everyone in a `Mono.fromCallable` that is on its own elastic scheduler

Answer (score 0):

First of all your requests are not executed "concurrently".

Lets talk through your code.

```
List<Request> bodies;
List<Mono<Response>> monos = requests.stream().map(bodies -> prepareMono(body)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

you have a `List<Requests>` somewhere that you haven't declared. Why is this a list? Lists are imperative, this should be a `Flux`.

You create n number of Monos that are going to do n number of requests. Why this is called `prepareMono` i have no idea, its not preparing a mono.

```
List<Response> results = Flux.merge(monos).collectList().onErrorContinue((ex, value) -> {
        //TODO how can I access the <Request> here who caused the exception
        errors.put(<request>, ex);
    }).block();
```

So here you take your list of "soon to be calling rest calls" and merging them into a `Flux`. What does the API say about `Flux#merge`

> Merge data from Publisher sequences contained in an Iterable into an
>   interleaved merged sequence.

It creates a flux from a `List<Mono<T>>` without considering order. So they will be emitted one by one but it may not keep your original order. Its still an *iterable sequence*.

then you do a `Flux#collectList` and the api states

> Collect all elements emitted by this Flux into a List that is emitted by the resulting Mono when this sequence completes.

So when the flux *sequence completes* you go back to a `Mono<List<T>>` containing the response and then on that `Mono` you want to catch an error when it is going to emit that list, using a `onErrorContinue`

And on top of that you want to `block` everything.

You are mixing and jumping around from the imperative world and to the reactive world and then back to the imperative and jumping back and fourth between List, Flux and Mono.

We need to sort out some basics.

**Mono**
One thing. It can contain a list of n things. That list is the one thing.

**Flux**
Many things, can be a thing or many things in a list. Can be many lists because a list is a thing.

**List**
Is a sort of a `Flux` so dont use lists of monos, use a flux.

Now that we know these basics. we can see that in your code, that `Flux.merge(monos)` will return a `Flux<Response>` (a list of mono responses) so the flux will on each emit **in sequence** do a rest call and return the response and emit it.

But what you are then doing is `collectList`. Collect list has to wait until *this sequence completes*. All calls have to be made and all has to have gone well because you want a `Mono<List<Response>>`.

To get a list full of responses, all responses must have been successful.

You then error handle on the Mono to see if it fails to emit that list.

You need to handle errors on each rest call as they are done, and they are done sequentially from the flux.

```
Flux.merge(monos)
    .onErrorContinue((throwable, request) -> {
        // error handling
    })
    .collectList();
```

But you are overcomplicating things this is how i would write your code.

```
final List<Response> responseList = Flux.fromIterable(requestList)
            .parallel(2)
            .runOn(Schedulers.parallel())
            .doOnNext(this::fooService.get)
            .onErrorContinue((throwable, o) -> {
                // add to map here
            }).doFinally(signalType -> {
                // check if map is empty if not throw exception
            }).collectList()
              .block();
```

And last but not least, i don't know how many times i have had to tell people this.

**Webflux is not concurrent by default, Mono's and Flux's are executed as they get emitted in a sequential chain unless you use parallel flux in combination with async consumers or perform everything in flatmaps**

If you want execute in parallel you need to use [Parallel Fluxes](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#advanced-parallelizing-parralelflux). And if you want concurrency you need to use something like `@Async` annotated methods in combination with parallel execution. Or elastic schedulers with Monos.

Comment: If you use flatMap on Flux, you can get concurrency (assuming inner publishers publish on different threads) without switching to parallel Flux. It's important to differentiate between concurrency and parallelism.

Comment: yes but my statement states it is not concurrent by default. There are multiple options, you can use async methods in a flux in combination with parallel. I have updated the last parts

Comment: Wether or not it is called parallel or concurrent, I just want my web requests to be emitted all at once, and then block until all of them are received.

Comment: Regarding your comments: I have a `List<Requests>` because I get this via external webservice calls. So I could of course transform that list into a Flux (should I?), but the source remains a list that I cannot control.

Comment: then there are some more questions, is your app a full webflux application or is it a regular application?

Comment: It's a regular application (blocking webservice), my goal is just to emit the webclient requests to a further remote webservice all at once. Because I want to aggregate multiple different external resources, and not want to call them in sequence...

Comment: then why dont you just `webClient.post().syncBody(body).retrieve().bodyToMono(Response.class).block()` and use `@Async` instead, and skip Fluxes and monos. This is not a webflux question.

Comment: @Yossarian `.flatMap()` works indeed with the suggested code.

Comment: @ThomasAndolf Would there be any advantage using `Future`s with `@Async` over `WebClient` here? Why not simply using the `Flux` to combine the results? Would there be any advantage one over the other?

Comment: i cant tell if there is any advantages or not sorry

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```java
Flux.fromIterable(requests)
    .flatMap(request -> execute(request))
    .doOnNext(result -> {
        if (result.throwable != null)
        {
            Request request = result.request;
            Throwable throwable = result.throwable;
            // do something
        }
    });

private Mono<Result> execute(Request request)
{
    return WEB_CLIENT.post().syncBody(request).retrieve()
                     .bodyToMono(Response.class)
                     .map(response -> new Result(request, response, null))
                     .onErrorResume(e -> Mono.just(new Result(request, null, e)));
}

private class Result
{
    private Request request;
    private Response response;
    private Throwable throwable;

    private Result(Request request, Response response, Throwable throwable)
    {
        this.request = request;
        this.response = response;
        this.throwable = throwable;
    }
}
```

Collecting the requests-errors in a map outside the reactive chain is quite ugly, though.